# How can I use HTTP PING in Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm trying to use the [HTTP PING](http://www.sitepoint.com/new-html5-attributes-hyperlinks-download-media-ping/#the-ping-attribute) request, and my action works as a test as a direct GET request, but when I test it in action, Yii returns `400 Bad Request`.

```
<a href="<?= Url::toRoute(['shopping/ping', 'id' => (string)$item->productId, 
  'category' => (string)$item->primaryCategory->categoryId]) ?>">test</a>
<a href="<?= $item->viewItemURL ?>" ping="<?= Url::toRoute(['shopping/ping', 'id' => (string)$item->productId, 
  'category' => (string)$item->primaryCategory->categoryId]) ?>">
```

This is the request sent by the browser:

```
POST /aa/web/index.php?r=shopping%2Fping&id=102712943&category=122930 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:81
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 4
Origin: http://localhost:81
Ping-From: http://localhost:81/aa/web/index.php?r=shopping%2Fsearch
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/ping
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Ping-To: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Oster-TSSTTVVG01-4-Slice-Toaster-Oven-Black-Free-Shipping-New-/111355397466?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ...chocolate chip...

PING
```

This is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Fri, 20 Mar 2015 04:46:37 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1k DAV/2 PHP/5.6.6
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.6
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: ...
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

My guess is it's because of the content-type or because it was a POST request with URL parameters and the body didn't have the route.

Here it is as a `curl` request.

```
$ curl "http://localhost:81/aa/web/index.php?r=shopping"%"2Fping&id=102712943&category=122930" -H "Origin: http://localhost:81" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36" -H "Content-Type: text/ping" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Ping-From: http://localhost:81/aa/web/index.php?r=shopping"%"2Fsearch" -H "Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.1670952969.1415577943; _sp_id.1fff=1d72e39980ea4f9f.1418093158.62.1423448353.1420663798; _csrf=62bd0371770906a42eb6da654fb4345ba51adb9272a26d1dc8ce6d28908f6610a"%"3A2"%"3A"%"7Bi"%"3A0"%"3Bs"%"3A5"%"3A"%"22_csrf"%"22"%"3Bi"%"3A1"%"3Bs"%"3A32"%"3A"%"22Dq2_r1KD_6GR-rHBEm3b4g6foEKxFL5q"%"22"%"3B"%"7D; PHPSESSID=j4unbucemcp4pj1h87qimld596; _identity=df1823bd01881d804ff9655d79364c898d2ad574cc769f3a53fb104dde8e3f88a"%"3A2"%"3A"%"7Bi"%"3A0"%"3Bs"%"3A9"%"3A"%"22_identity"%"22"%"3Bi"%"3A1"%"3Bs"%"3A28"%"3A"%"22"%"5B"%"22100"%"22"%"2C"%"22test100key"%"22"%"2C2592000"%"5D"%"22"%"3B"%"7D" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" -H "Ping-To: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Oster-TSSTTVVG01-4-Slice-Toaster-Oven-Black-Free-Shipping-New-/111355397466?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0" --data-binary "PING"                 
...
<h1>Bad Request (#400)</h1>
```

I went back to my app and clicked on the debugger bar, and loaded the request that failed. This is the error and stack trace that it gives.

```
exception 'yii\web\BadRequestHttpException' with message 'Unable to verify your data submission.' in /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/AffiliateArbitrage/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Controller.php:110
Stack trace:
#0 /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/AffiliateArbitrage/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(149): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#1 /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/AffiliateArbitrage/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(455): yii\base\Controller->runAction('ping', Array)
#2 /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/AffiliateArbitrage/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(83): yii\base\Module->runAction('shopping/ping', Array)
#3 /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/AffiliateArbitrage/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#4 /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/AffiliateArbitrage/web/index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#5 {main}
```

How do I get this request to work?

Comment: Try to include CSRF token like that: `<?= Url::toRoute(['shopping/ping', 'id' => (string) $item->productId, 'category' => (string) $item->primaryCategory->categoryId, Yii::$app->request->csrfParam => Yii::$app->request->csrfToken,]) ?>`

Comment: It does actually include the _csrf cookie. I just left the cookies out because the line was really long. I tried it anyways, but it didn't help.

Comment: You have two links in the view file above - which one is not working, or are neither of them working?

Comment: @JoeMiller Yes there are two links. One is a direct link with anchor text `test` and the other is a `ping=` attribute. The direct link works. The `ping` attribute doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my understanding of the problem. Firstly, the error you are getting relates directly to csrf validation. The validation fails, so the request is never processed. When you click the link, you are making a GET request, so csrf validation is not called.

The ping attribute however submits a request via the POST method to the server. Because it's a POST method, Yii is expecting to find a valid csrf token in the body of the request, which is not found, because there is no form being submitted.

The fallback is to check the headers to see if there is a valid csrf token in the header HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN, so it may be that you can write some javascript to intercept the ping request and add the required header, taking the token from the existing cookie. My javascript isn't good enough to write that though, so I can't test it!

The other alternative would be to write a new controller class, override the beforeAction() method of the default controller to remove the csrf validation parts, and have your specific ShoppingController extend that new controller.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But the CSRF token is passed, in a cookie. You can see the cookie set in the `curl` request. `_csrf=62bd03717709...`

Comment: Yes, I know, but because it's a POST request, Yii isn't looking for the cookie there, it's looking for it in the body of the POST request, or in the header. That's why the validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was because CSRF and here is a solution:

```
  public function beforeAction($action) {
    // Yii::trace($action); // this will prevent debug bar from showing!
    if ($action->id == 'ping') $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
  }
```

I marked the other answer to give credit for the suggestion even though there was no example.